# Differentiate between column space, dimension of column space, and basis of column space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say if there is a matrix A:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

**What the column space of A?** : I am confused whether to exclude NON-pivot columns.

**What is the dimension of column space?** : The dimension of the column space or dimension of the basis of column space? Can be either 4 or 3?

**What is the basis of column space?** This is just the pivot columns. Is this the so called $\operatorname{Col}A$?

Comment: The space generated by columns is column space, then linearly independent columns are basis of column space, and number of basis is the dimension of column space.

Comment: okay that makes sense...why don't you put that as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column space is not a list of vectors so it's not clear what you mean when you ask if you should exclude non-pivot columns.  The column space is the linear span of the columns.  Each column (including the non-pivot columns) is contained in this space.

What you may be confusing yourself with is the column space vs. a *basis* for the column space.  A basis is indeed a list of columns and for a reduced matrix such as the one you have a basis for the column space is given by taking exactly the pivot columns (as you have said).  There are various notations for this, $\operatorname{Col}A$ is perfectly acceptable but don't be surprised if you see others.

As for the dimension of the column space, it's $3$, which is the number of elements in a basis, i.e., the number of pivot columns.

Comment: Great explanation. If someone were to ask if vector V is in the column space of matrix A, then [ A V ] would have to be consistent. Would that be a valid conjecture?

Comment: That is a true statement: $V$ is in the column space of $A$ if and only if the system of equations represented by the augmented matrix $[A \ V]$ has a solution.

Comment: And one more question. Can I conclude the basis of column space of Matrix A defines the vector space of `R^m` or a subspace of `R^m`?

Comment: The column space in this case is $\mathbb R^3$ but for other matrices it can be a proper subspace.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of column space of this matrix can not be 4, because dimension of column space=dimension of row space, and number of rows is 3, then the number of linearly independent rows is less than or equal to 3!

Comment: did you mean at most 3?

Comment: of course, less than or equal to 3!